# Is there any way to find a string's position and click on it using robotium?

Tags: android-activity, ui-automation, robotium, android

I have the following list appearing on UI of an android application which tells about the date and the temperature on that date.

```
temp      degree
11/01      --.-- c
11/02      21.7  c
11/03      22.5  c
```

Here I want to find the position of string `"--.--"` and then click on it, so that I can update the list. Is there any way to find the position of string?  I know that `solo.searchText()` will tell whether the string is present or not, but what about the position?

Comment: Is first "-" always on first position??

Comment: @BhanuSharma Yes and string should be exactly "--.--".

Comment: @BhanuSharma Even if the string is not "--.--", is there any other way to find the postion of a string and click on it?

Comment: and tell me one thing this string is only on first position or its position may be change some times

Comment: @BhanuSharma No it can change and there can be multiple "--.--" on a single list.

Comment: k then chk with String.equals(""); method if it is yes when u click then go ahead if not then nthng do

Comment: @BhanuSharma I can't find this function.  Can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 1):

```
// i think it will help you 

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
      int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     if(yourliststring.trim().equals("--.--"))
                                   {
                                      //your condition
                                    }
                             else
                                {    
                                     //your condition

                                    }

                 }
            });
```

Comment: Got "Multiple markers at this line - 1) OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type 2) listviewchild cannot be resolved."

Comment: dear u wrote list view as it is noooooooooooooo there u mention your list view name what ever that is dear..just mention your listview name in place of listview

Comment: what about "yourliststring" ?

Comment: yourliststring is "--.--" take this in any string and use this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what position you need, however if you need position on screen you can simple do:

```
TextView textView = solo.getText("--.--"); // or solo.getText(Pattern.quote("--.--")); if needed
int[] xy = new int[2];
textView.getLocationOnScreen(xy);
final int viewWidth = textView.getWidth();
final int viewHeight = textView.getHeight();
final float x = xy[0] + (viewWidth / 2.0f);
final float y = xy[1] + (viewHeight / 2.0f);
```

this way you have central point of view (x, y).

If you need position of text in list, you can do:

```
private int getPosition(ListView listView, String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
        Object o = listView.getAdapter.getItemAtPosition(i);
        if (o instanceof TextView) {
            if (((TextView)o).getText().toString().equals(text)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1; // not found
}
```

you can call it for instance this way (set proper parameters):

```
int position = getPosition((ListView) solo.getView(ListView.class, 0), "--.--");
```

Everything written without testing and even compiling, however main idea should be fine.

Comment: I tried the third option but it gives "The method getPostion() is undefined for the type file_name."

Answer (score 0):

I got a simple way to find and click on the string

```
if(solo.searchText("--.--")){
            solo.clickLongOnText("--.--");
        }
```

All I need is to click on the string "--.--".